# Find a word by line number

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nlp

I am doing an nlp project. I comparing the results of my system with the annotated ground truth accompanied by the data set. The results of the system give an offset ID that are based on character number. However, the ground truth is by line number, and token number based on where it is situated in the line. For example, consider this ground truth:

```
m="lasix" 26:7 26:7
```

In here, the 26 refers to line 26 of the corpus and 7 is the number of the token in the line. i tried to convert this offset number to character index by creating an character index generator below.

```
 def all_occurences(file, str):
        initial = 0
        file = file.replace('\n', ' ')
        while True:
            initial = file.find(str, initial)
            if initial == -1: return
            yield initial
            initial += len(str)
```

This works sometimes. BUT, in the ground truth annotation a medication name might be mentioned only once but considered as two entities based on reason.

For example:

```
corpus = "motrin for pain and headache."
```

In this case, motrin are 2 separate identities:

```
m="motrin" 26:7 26:7, reason="pain"
m="motrin" 26:7 26:7, reason="headache"
```

Clearly, in this case, my function fails because it sees motrin once.

Any suggestions on how to convert line number offset to character number offset?

Thank you!